# How to make a Intellij jetty run configuration run on JDK7 (OS X)

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, jetty, java-7

I have oracle' s JDK 7 installed alongside the Apple JDK6.
The JDK 7 is registered in IntelliJ (12.x) and my project is set to JDK7.

I created a jetty run configuration, but it seems he is running the jetty server against the JDK6.
Of course this gives a: org/eclipse/jetty/start/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Project Settings > Project set the project SDK to the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

If the solution above doesn't work, try Run Configuration -> JRE -> Select Execution environment -> JavaSE-1.7